# Metamask not returning current account address with web3js and ganache

Tags: web3js, metamask, ganache

How to return the address of my current account from `Metamask`? I have tried with `web3.eth.getCoinbase()` but this and metamask has two different address.

`web3.eth.getCoinbase()` returns me the first account from the list of accounts provided by `Ganache`.

What I need to do to resolve this?

Thanks

**P.S.:**

I am following the tutorial from [here](http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/the-ultimate-ethereum-dapp-tutorial) and 2019 updated Github code is [here](https://github.com/dappuniversity/election/blob/2019_update/src/js/app.js).

The below code is the problem:

```
web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });
```

It returns `null` even if I have address of my account in metamask and yes I have imported an account given by `Ganache` onto `Metamask`.

Comment: just ADD connection http://localhost:3000 in setting of metamask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch off the privacy mode, which is under security and privacy in the metamask settings. Then refresh the page, that should display your current account address.

Comment: I don't see privacy mode anymore.  Has it been deleted from the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

To get current account selected in Metamask: **web3.eth.accounts[0]**.

To make above code work with metamask, set coinbase on ganache, and then configure and use custom RPC url (provided by ganache ) in metamask.

Comment: `web3.eth.accounts[0]` Isn't that outdated.

Comment: I can get first account from the list of address returned from `web3.eth.getAccounts()` but that address and the metamask account address are not same which should be same actually, shown in the tutorial.

Comment: web3.eth.getAccounts() will return accounts controlled by ethereum node, whereas metamask itself is a wallet with its own addresses, which are different from addresses created on node. However you could import ethereum node addresses in metamask manually with import account option.   And, web3.eth.accounts[0] is not deprecated, Metamask uses web3 version 0.20.X.

Comment: Doesn't this just return the first account? Not the current?

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped, "manually connect" the current side on Metamask.
[image]